# How to send JMSType in jmeter

Tags: jms, jmeter

I am trying to send jms message with JMeter (Publisher or Point-to-point), but I am not able to send JMSType.
If I put it to JMS properties with name JMSType it finishes with error:

> Response message: The property name 'JMSType' is illegal since it starts with JMS

Comment: So the answer is no it is not possible. I've changed it in jMeter sources for me.
It is probably specific for queue vendors. Any of them allow setting properties as text property the others requires to set it directly to message as there is the JMSType parameter and when you try to set the string 'JMS*' parameter tou got exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is no it is not possible. I've changed it in jMeter sources for me. It is probably specific for queue vendors. Any of them allow setting properties as text property the others requires to set it directly to message as there is the JMSType parameter and when you try to set the string 'JMS*' parameter tou got exception.

Answer (score 2):

By default Jmeter does not include any JMS implementation jars in its distribution. This must be downloaded from the JMS provider and put in the lib directory of Jmeter.

I have tested this in Jmeter 2.9 and 2.13. You can set JMS header properties including JMSType in the JMS properties tab and publish a message successfully without any errors.